# Microsoft Word creating bookmarks when copying text

Tags: microsoft-word, bookmarks

Ok, this is an odd one. A few days ago, I had to work with bookmarks in Microsoft Word 2019 for Mac to customise a table of content. I can't recall making any changes in the Preferences.

Ever since, when I open an existing document in Word, it will put grey square brackets around text that I select and copy from it using cmd+C. It will also add a bookmark around the copied text and recognise the document as edited and ask me to save changes when closing.

[image]

What is going on and how can I stop this behaviour?

Comment: Do you get the same results when right-clicking and selecting copy?

Comment: @Karen927 Yes. Also when using Edit > Copy.

Comment: It could be a corrupt normal.dotm, have you tried resetting it?

Answer (score 2):

[Apparently](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/why-is-word-suddenly-creating-two-olelink/3808b279-6bc6-4db0-9a1e-06925b7f31cf) that is a longstanding Microsoft Word bug that occurs when using clipboard managers. In my case I had a cliboard manager configured in [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai).

Deleting the clipboard manager keyboard shortcut will resolve the issue (disabling it is not sufficient).

**Update**: 
I [filed a bug report with BetterTouchTool](https://community.folivora.ai/t/btt-clipboard-manager-causing-bookmark-creation-in-microsoft-word-even-when-disabled), but my feeling is that only Microsoft can really resolve the issue.